# Cannot import mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, connector

I installed the python mysql connector with pip, and pip list shows it's there. However,

```
import mysql.connector
```

says mysql is not a package. I kept (un)installing as recommended by some of the other posts, but problem still persists. Please advise.
Thanks